# Rails Configurable Model collides with ActiveSupport::Configurable::Configuration:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, activesupport

I have a `Configurable` model:

```
# /models/configuration.rb
class Configuration < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

When I reference `Configurable` in my `pages_controller`, it works fine:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def search
    @description = Configuration.find_by_name('description') || nil
  end
end
```

But when I reference it in my `application_controller.rb`, like so

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    def get_menu
       @menu = Configuration.where(name: 'menu') || nil
    end
end
```

I get the error `undefined method 'where' for ActiveSupport::Configurable::Configuration:Class`. How can I prevent my `Configuration` model and `ActiveSupport::Configurable::Configuration:Class` from colliding like this, or reference my `Configuration` model directly?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to prefix it

```
::Configuration.where(name: 'menu')
```

Notice the `::` before the class name. They force the interpreter to use the `Configuration` class in the main namespace, rather than one in the `ActiveSupport` namespace.

Comment: That worked for me, and I'll mark it correct when the timer is over. I'm curious if something implied before the `::`?